# Android: Use spinner text in CursorAdapter

Tags: android, listview, cursor, spinner, simplecursoradapter

I've got an ListView that is filled with an SimpleCursorAdapter. One of the Fields that should be displayed in this view (TBTsqlHelperBudgets.KEY_INTERVAL) is stored in the DB as int (index of the spinner, that is used for input). But I would like to show the text rather than the index in the ListView. Any Suggestions?

```
public class TBTTManageBudgetsActivity extends Activity {
    // ...
    // some stuff 
    // ...

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // ...
        // some stuff 
        // ...
                cursor = getBudgets();
                String[] uiBindFrom = { TBTsqlHelperBudgets.KEY_NAME, TBTsqlHelperBudgets.KEY_BUDGET, TBTsqlHelperBudgets.KEY_INTERVAL };               
                int[] uiBindTo = { R.id.name, R.id.budget, R.id.interval};
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                CursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this.getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list_budgets_item, cursor, uiBindFrom, uiBindTo);                
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        // ...
        // some stuff 
        // ...
    }
    // ...
    // some stuff 
    // ...
}
```

By the way: The spinner is set up using an xml array:

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.intervals, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
```

with the xml:

```
<resources>
    <string-array name="intervals">
        <item>per day</item>
        <item>per week</item>
        <item>per month</item>
        <item>per year</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to display the text (as opposed to being able to edit it), you can use something like this to do conversions or lookups on the fly.  It simply wraps your Cursor and you set which columns need special handling.  All others are handled by the underlying Cursor object:

```
package com.awc.util;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.database.CharArrayBuffer;
import android.database.ContentObserver;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.DataSetObserver;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class ConversionAndLookupCursor implements Cursor {
private static final String TAG = ConversionAndLookupCursor.class.getSimpleName();


private Cursor wrapped;
private Converter converters[];


public ConversionAndLookupCursor(Cursor wrapped) {
    if(wrapped == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("wrapped");
    }

    this.wrapped = wrapped;
    this.converters = new Converter[wrapped.getColumnCount()];
}


@Override
public void close() {
    wrapped.close();
}

@Override
public void copyStringToBuffer(int columnIndex, CharArrayBuffer buffer) {
    Converter c;
    String s;


    Log.d(TAG, "Converting " + columnIndex);
    c = converters[columnIndex];
    if(c != null) {
        s = c.convertFrom(wrapped.getLong(columnIndex));
        buffer.data = s.toCharArray();
    } else {
        wrapped.copyStringToBuffer(columnIndex, buffer);
    }
}

@Override
public void deactivate() {
    wrapped.deactivate();
}

@Override
public byte[] getBlob(int columnIndex) {
    return wrapped.getBlob(columnIndex);
}

@Override
public int getColumnCount() {
    return wrapped.getColumnCount();
}

@Override
public int getColumnIndex(String columnName) {
    return wrapped.getColumnIndex(columnName);
}

@Override
public int getColumnIndexOrThrow(String columnName)
        throws IllegalArgumentException {
    return wrapped.getColumnIndexOrThrow(columnName);
}

@Override
public String getColumnName(int columnIndex) {
    return wrapped.getColumnName(columnIndex);
}

@Override
public String[] getColumnNames() {
    return wrapped.getColumnNames();
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return wrapped.getCount();
}

@Override
public double getDouble(int columnIndex) {
    return wrapped.getDouble(columnIndex);
}

@Override
public Bundle getExtras() {
    return wrapped.getExtras();
}

@Override
public float getFloat(int columnIndex) {
    return wrapped.getFloat(columnIndex);
}

@Override
public int getInt(int columnIndex) {
    return wrapped.getInt(columnIndex);
}

@Override
public long getLong(int columnIndex) {
    return wrapped.getLong(columnIndex);
}

@Override
public int getPosition() {
    return wrapped.getPosition();
}

@Override
public short getShort(int columnIndex) {
    return wrapped.getShort(columnIndex);
}

@Override
public String getString(int columnIndex) {
    Converter c;
    Long value = null;
    String s;


    c = converters[columnIndex];
    if(c != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Converting in getString(" + columnIndex + ")");
        if(!wrapped.isNull(columnIndex)) {
            value = wrapped.getLong(columnIndex);
        }
        s = c.convertFrom(value);
    } else {
        s = wrapped.getString(columnIndex);
    }

    return s;
}

@Override
public boolean getWantsAllOnMoveCalls() {
    return wrapped.getWantsAllOnMoveCalls();
}

@Override
public boolean isAfterLast() {
    return wrapped.isAfterLast();
}

@Override
public boolean isBeforeFirst() {
    return wrapped.isBeforeFirst();
}

@Override
public boolean isClosed() {
    return wrapped.isClosed();
}

@Override
public boolean isFirst() {
    return wrapped.isFirst();
}

@Override
public boolean isLast() {
    return wrapped.isLast();
}

@Override
public boolean isNull(int columnIndex) {
    return wrapped.isNull(columnIndex);
}

@Override
public boolean move(int offset) {
    return wrapped.move(offset);
}

@Override
public boolean moveToFirst() {
    return wrapped.moveToFirst();
}

@Override
public boolean moveToLast() {
    return wrapped.moveToLast();
}

@Override
public boolean moveToNext() {
    return wrapped.moveToNext();
}

@Override
public boolean moveToPosition(int position) {
    return wrapped.moveToPosition(position);
}

@Override
public boolean moveToPrevious() {
    return wrapped.moveToPrevious();
}

@Override
public void registerContentObserver(ContentObserver observer) {
    wrapped.registerContentObserver(observer);
}

@Override
public void registerDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {
    wrapped.registerDataSetObserver(observer);
}

@Override
public boolean requery() {
    return wrapped.requery();
}

@Override
public Bundle respond(Bundle extras) {
    return wrapped.respond(extras);
}

@Override
public void setNotificationUri(ContentResolver cr, Uri uri) {
    wrapped.setNotificationUri(cr, uri);
}

@Override
public void unregisterContentObserver(ContentObserver observer) {
    wrapped.unregisterContentObserver(observer);
}

@Override
public void unregisterDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {
    wrapped.unregisterDataSetObserver(observer);
}


////////////////////////////////////
// DATA CONVERSION STUFF
////////////////////////////////////
public void setDateConversion(int column) {
    converters[column] = new DateConverter();
}

public void setLookupConversion(int column, Cursor lookup, int lookupColumn) {
    converters[column] = new LookupConverter(lookup, lookupColumn);
}

public void clearConversion(int column) {
    converters[column] = null;
}

private interface Converter {
    public String convertFrom(Object value);
}

private class DateConverter implements Converter {
    private DateFormat fmt;


    public DateConverter() {
        fmt = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT);
    }

    public String convertFrom(Object value) {
        String s = null;


        if(value != null && value instanceof Long) {
            s = fmt.format(new Date((Long)value));
        }

        return s;
    }
}

private class LookupConverter implements Converter {
    private Cursor lookup;
    private int lookupColumn;

    public LookupConverter(Cursor lookup, int column) {
        if(lookup == null) throw new NullPointerException("lookup");

        this.lookup = lookup;
        this.lookupColumn = column;
    }

    public String convertFrom(Object id) {
        String s = null;


        if(id != null && id instanceof Long) {
            lookup.moveToPosition(((Long)id).intValue());
            s = lookup.getString(lookupColumn);
        }

        return s;
    }
}
}
```